# swagger with spring webflux cannot find Publisher«ResponseEntity«object»»

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-webflux

I am trying to use swagger with spring webflux, but for some reason it gives an error message

> Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer:
> /definitions/Publisher«ResponseEntity«object»» does not exist in
> document
> [image]

here it is the sawagger config

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private final SwaggerDocketBuilder builder;

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Reactive Documentation")
            .description("Reactive API Documentation")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(this.apiInfo())
            .enable(true)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

I have added             `.genericModelSubstitutes(Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class);`

the new `docket()`

```
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(this.apiInfo())
            .enable(true)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
.genericModelSubstitutes(Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class);
    }
```